# C# Repetitive code with null check

Tags: c#, rpc, null-check

I'm working with RPC(protobuf-remote) and I need to do some checking in case the other end(server) is down. Let's say I've lot's of RPC methods, like:

```
public FirstObj First(string one, string two)
{
    if (rpc == null)
        return (FirstObj)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FirstObj));

    return rpc.First(one, two);
}

public SecondObj Second(string one)
{
    if (rpc == null)
        return (SecondObj)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SecondObj));

    return rpc.Second(one);
}

public ThirdObj Third()
{
    if (rpc == null)
        return (ThirdObj)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ThirdObj));

    return rpc.Third();
}
```

Is there anyway to change this repetitive null-checking code? So I could write something like:

```
public FirstObj First(string one, string two)
{
    return rpc.First(one, two);
}
```

Which would do null-checking and would create object by it's type if RPC server is down, so I will get default values of required object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create such extension method:

```
public static class RpcExtension
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(this RPC rpc, Func<RPC, T> func)
        where T: class , new ()
    {
        if (rpc == null)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
        return func(rpc);
    }
}
```

for this usage:

```
var first = rpc.GetObject(r => r.First(a, b));
```

Comment: Or `var first = rpc.GetObject(r => r?.First(a, b));`

Comment: @Dr.Fre that is not needed. If r is null, First will be not called anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code with a generic method:

```
private static T Make<T>() {
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
public FirstObj First(string one, string two) {
    return rpc == null ? Make<FirstObj>() : rpc.First(one, two);
}
public SecondObj Second(string one) {
    return rpc == null ? Make<SecondObj>() : rpc.Second(one);
}
public ThirdObj Third() {
    return rpc == null ? Make<ThirdObj>() : rpc.Third();
}
```

If `FirstObj`, `SecondObj`, and `ThirdObj` types are all classes, not `struct`s or primitives, and `rpc` never returns `null` for them, you can do this:

```
public static T RpcOrDefault<T>(T obj) where T : class {
    return obj ?? (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

and call it

```
FirstObj first = RpcOrDefault(rpc?.First(one, two));
//                               ^
```

Note the `?` in `?.` which shields you from `null` reference exceptions.